# Bulk adding text to videos

Tags: premiere, video-editor, editing, final-cut-pro

I have around 300 music videos and i need to add the usual text (animation or whatever) to all of them. (Just like MTV for example, each video has this text on them lasting for first few seconds of the video so ppl can read what they are listening too).

Song title:

Release year:

Album title:

etc...

Is there any way to batch process this amount of videos with any kind of software ? Basicly, only the text changes on each video, position and everything else would remain exacly the same.

Answer (score 1):

With Adobe After Effects and a script such as PT_TextEdit, you'd be able to do something like this.  You create the text styles you want to use, add all the text to a spreadsheet or google sheet, then run it through PT-TextEdit, which will generate a load of different comps for you with the different names.  You can then batch export all the comps.
http://aescripts.com/pt_textedit/

Comment: Unfortunately i did not mange to do it with any options written here. Would be great if someone could write a tutorial. If nothing else works, i will do it manually for each video, but some advice on which software to use to make it fast as possible would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in [Sony Vegas Pro](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/vegasproedit) using [this plugin](http://vegasaur.com/text-generation-wizard) (Text Wizard)

In a nutshell:

1. Prepare your text and copy it to the clipboard (see below)
2. Add your clips to the timeline
3. Run *Text Wizard* and choose *Create text at events*
4. Import text from the clipboard

Your text should be in the following format:

```
Song title:
Release year:
Album title:
(empty line)
Song title:
Release year:
Album title:
(empty line)
etc.
```

Comment: Could you please add slighty more information? In case the link goes down there's no easy way to find out what tool you're talking about and what it does. Some quotes from the website + the tool title would help a lot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not so good with Sony Vegas but i will try this. After i do this is it possible to export each clip separately like i imported them ?

Comment: @bigbrother2010: yes, other tools in Vegasaur Toolkit allow you to create regions on top of your clips, and render those regions as separate files.